# Grid like Flatlist component with header looking the same as rows

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

In `react-native` I am using `FlatList` component for rendering a grid-like list of data that looks like:

[image]

However, I want to make the first row (or header) with **bold text stylesheet**. Do I need to `renderHeader` as another `FlatList` or is there any better solution for this?

My code for this table:

```
    <View style={stylesCustom.container}>
        <FlatList 
            data={ data }
            renderItem={({item}) =><View style={stylesCustom.GridViewBlockStyle}>
                <Text style={styles.description} > {item.key} </Text></View>}
            numColumns={5}
        />
    </View>

const stylesCustom = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        flex:1,
        marginTop: 20
    },
    GridViewBlockStyle: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#00BCD4',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: 'black'
    },       
    GridViewInsideTextItemStyle: {
        color: '#fff',
        padding: 10,
        fontSize: 18,
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
}
```

Comment: I think you need a section as a title... try to look the SectionList component

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo tried out using `SectionList`. Seems like another styles problem (if possible) to make it look like a grid, but `FlatList` also has `renderHeader` method, so there's no much difference.

Comment: well, there are no columns attribute at SectionList, I just read this. I suggest to use SectionList with one column, but each row, using flex, could have your 5 items. You can spread your original array in an array of arrays: [ [item1, item2, item3, item4, item5], [item6 ...]], and then, your renderer can do the work.